# How to print PDF files in Android?

Tags: android, pdf

I have some PDF files in the app and I want to enable users to print them.

I have seen PrinterManager class but it looks like too much boilerplate code.

Is there some kind of Intent that will open some system screen to handle printing like choosing printer and printing?

I have used a few PDF apps and they are opening this screen for printing.

How I can make something like this?

[image]

Comment: "Is there some kind of Intent that will open some system screen to handle printing like choosing printer and printing?" -- there is no `ACTION_PRINT` or the equivalent in the Android SDK. "I have used a few PDF apps and they are opening this screen for printing" -- examine Logcat and see if they are starting some activity, and if so, from what app. Otherwise, presumably that is your device's representation of the `PrintManager` UI.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I am looking for the exact same thing - having PDF files and need to print them by choosing a WiFi printer

Answer (score 1):

My Requirement also same. I found solution and tested on mobile. Solution exactly what you are looking. Please refer.
https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Printing/PrintManager

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want create your own code to print the document in your app.

You could try to implement an Intent to launch Chrome or other browser passing the path of the file as Uri and open the PDF in the browser, then the user could print the document using the browser.

Launching the intent:

```
//Launch the intent to open the file with default browser.
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(path_to_file));
startActivity(i);
```

You can print using Chrome: Settings -> Share -> Choose Print and select your printer.

I hope it can helps you.